# Remove Safari web inspector ruler

Tags: safari, development

How do I disable the rulers in Safari's WebInspector?

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Apparently there is a hidden button in the elements tab that toggles the rulers. 
[image]

Comment: Bizarre... just spent ages looking for that myself!

Comment: amazing ! how do you know that ;)

Comment: The Safari Technology Preview has a visible button for this on that position.

Comment: HAHAHA

Those stupid rulers were driving me crazy and I cannot believe this is the real solution.  Too ridiculous.